# Twilio .NET API - delete SMS messages?

Tags: .net, twilio

Is it possible to delete messages using the C# API for Twilio?

If not, is it possible at all to delete messages using REST calls?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

Just to clarify, you want to delete a Queued SMS message, or you want to delete the log that is generated when you send an SMS?

Currently there is no way to delete SMS messages using the REST API, and therefore there is nothing exposed by the .NET library.  You can however delete the log entry created when an SMS is sent using the Notifications API.

```
var client = new TwilioRestClient("{ACCOUNTSID}", "{AUTHTOKEN}");
client.DeleteNotification("{notificationSid}");
```

Hope that helps.

Devin